# Apache Airflow cross dag dependency

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have Dag A  which start  at 17:00 PM  and there are three tasks. Task 1 run trigger  then Task 2 will run which depend upon on other file availability in the directory from other system,so we have not defined the execution time. We want to trigger the Task in DAG B which depends on Task 1 completion of DAG A.  (In simple term  only on the success of task 2 in DAG A can task in DAG B can be triggered  without defining the execution time  in DAG A)

Comment: You can use `ExternalTaskMarker` and `ExternalTaskSensor` to achieve this I think...  https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/sensors/external_task/index.html

Comment: Found this link very useful - https://www.cloudwalker.io/2021/09/26/airflow-external-task-sensor/

Comment: Ramajayam Gopi were u able to solve your problem?